# fseek() doesn't seek to the correct record even with the correct syntax

Tags: c, fseek

i am a beginner in c and i am trying to search for a record that is in a binary file based on what the user inputs and using fseek it doesn't return any record at all.

```
typedef struct books {
    int ISBN_num;
    char title[60];
    char authorfname[60],authorlname[60];
    char accession_num[7];
    char available[4];
    da borrowdate;
    da returndate;
    char borrowtype[9];
} bks;    

if((bk_temp=fopen("book.dat","rb"))!=NULL){
        puts("Enter ISBN of book you're searching for");
        scanf("%d",&isbn);
            system("cls");
            fseek(bk_temp,sizeof(temp)*(isbn-1),SEEK_SET);
            fread(&temp, sizeof(temp), 1, bk_temp);
            if (temp.ISBN_num == isbn) {
                printf("Title: %s", temp.title);
                printf("Author: %s %s", temp.authorfname, temp.authorlname);
                printf("Accession Number: %s", temp.accession_num);
                printf("Availability: %s", temp.available);
                printf("ISBN Number: %i", temp.ISBN_num);
                getch();
                return temp;
            }else{
                printf("Record not found");
            }
    fclose(bk_temp);
```

Comment: How are the books stored? Do you really store the book information using ISBN as the index? That's going to be a VERY sparse file. We don't know enough information to answer.

Comment: ISBNs used to be 10-digit numbers; they're now 13-digit numbers, I believe.  The tenth digit is a check-sum (and is occasionally an X, to boot). Do you really have enough space to be seeking to the position for an actual ISBN such as 0-13-110362-8 (which is the ISBN for K&R 2nd Edition)?  It would be instructive to know how the file was created.  Also, don't forget to output newlines at the end of output lines.  And check that operations such as `scanf()` and `fread()` are successful.  You also return without closing the file on those rare occasions when a book is found.

Comment: Please provide more context for the format of the structure.

Comment: it's school work and the isbn is required as the index for the file and it's 4 digits long for school purposes and remembering purposes as well.

Comment: the file was first created with blank records as to set the file size and then updated with useful records@JonathanLeffler